# Href links are not working on mobile view. Half page href links are working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website [www.tellmequotes.com](http://www.tellmequotes.com). Its working fine over the desktop view but when i check it on my Samsung s3 most of the links are not working.
If you open the page there are some author images you can click over them if you are on desktop but when its on mobile view it is not working. I removed the infolinks script but still it is not working. Site is divided into 2 column that Left side column is creating issue.

If you scroll down on mobile and when it goes to "Celebrate" point than you will see images are clickable but above images are not.

Comment: I removed the following line and then it is working. Might be a problem with some addons / scripts ? `<h2 class="bigh2">Celebrate</h2>`

Comment: You should generally put an example of your code rather than just linking to a website. That said, bootstrap works better if you use the `row` class. Put `<div class="row">` around each of your sections and that should fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick solution you can use this class 'authorbox' on devices as you've used it for each box.

```
.authorbox {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: @Vivek It is entirely because your question is not well written. It makes a valid question but not represented well. You should put some codes I guess because experts may not want to browse through the website, inspect it and find the responsible piece of code.

Comment: BUt the thing is if i know the code i will validate it.

Comment: This fix definitely solves the problem but it doesn't remedy the underlying DOM issues - if you inspect the elements on the page you will see that the containing `<div>` has no height and the subsequent `<h2>` elements are enormous and stretch up the page - the `.row` class is a very important part of a bootstrap layout.

Comment: You're right of course, I mainly said that so that @Vivek is aware that there is an underlying issue causing the problem and it will probably cause others.

Comment: yeah you're absolutely right I've written 'quick response' and later I wanted to edit but Since you've already posted..I didn't plus people downgrading his que too.

Comment: Ok i got it i will always consider your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the bootstrap `row` class to split up your sections.

e.g.

```
<div id="quotesList">
  <h2 class="bigh2">Trending Authors</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 authorbox text-center"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 authorbox text-center"></div>
        <!--etc-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```